# While loop in test bench of and gate. getting no output

Tags: verilog

I have written a simple test bench for and gate. My code and test bench was working fine. Now what I want to do is " I am trying to implement a while loop for my cases". I am not getting syntax error but not seeing any output. can any body tell my mistake?.

```
timescale 1ns / 100ps


int count=0;
module and_gate_test;

    // Inputs
    reg in1_t;
    reg in2_t;

    // Outputs
    wire out_t;

    // Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
    and_gate and_gate_1 (in1_t,in2_t,out_t);


    initial 
    begin
        // Initialize Inputs
        //case 0
        while(count==100){
        in1_t <= 0;
        in2_t <= 0;
        #1 $display ("out_t=%b",out_t);
                //case 1
        in1_t <= 1;
        in2_t <= 1;
        #1 $display ("out_t=%b",out_t);

        //case2
        in1_t <= 0;
        in2_t <= 1;
        #1 $display ("out_t=%b",out_t);

        //case3
        in1_t <= 1;
        in2_t <= 0;
        #1 $display ("out_t=%b",out_t);

       count++; }
        // Add stimulus here

    end

endmodule
```

Comment: May be better suited for http://electronics.stackexchange.com (remember, Verilog is a hardware synthesis language, not a programming language).  [More info](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90472/how-far-am-i-allowed-to-take-verilog-and-vhdl-questions).

Comment: @JonathonReinhart is correct you may also get good answers over on [electonicsSE](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/) but HDL questions do tend to get good answers here.

Answer (score 2):

hey i think you may want

```
 while( count <= 100)
```

you were never getting into the while loop because you are starting at zero so

```
while(count==100)
```

never evaluates to true

Comment: Yes, that is because I tried with every possible combination.It is not working with while(count<=100) also. I think we need to add mathematical library for doing count++ or add library for while loop. Not getting any idea.

Comment: you should just do count = count +1                                                        

also, i would recommend using blocking assignments "=" instead of non-blocking here "<=" this is for a lot of reasons that if you would like to read into further look at cumming's paper "verilog styles that kill'

Answer (score 1):

the while loop you used will never be executed as count will never be equal to 100 as Alex Rellim said. It should be like

`while(count<=100)`

and also count++ will not work in verilog. Use

`count = count + 1`

instead of count++.

And also while loop should have begin and end instead of curly braces.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of problems:

1. Curry brackets (e.i. `{` and `}`) for the while-loop need to be replaced by `begin` and `end` respectively

   - The simulator has a bug if it is not generating a syntax error ans the current code doesn't follow Verilog or SystemVerilog allowed usage.
2. `int count=0;` needs to be inside the module

   - *Note*: `int` is SystemVerilog. Use `integer` if you want to strictly follow IEEE Std 1364. `int` is fine if you want to utilize IEEE Std 1800. `int` defaults as `32'd0` while `integer` defaults as `32'dX`.
3. `while(count==100)` should be `while(count<=100)` or `while(count<100)`

   - if using `==` then the whole loop will be skipped since `count` is initialized as zero.
   - *Alternative Solution* for a loop: use `for(integer count=0; count<100; count++)`
     instead of `while(count<100)`

Answer (score 0):

`while(count == 100)`?!

[........8 more chars].

Comment: @downvoter: not that I care, but you presumably didn't notice that I gave the correct answer, in 21 chars, and then someone else came along and said the same thing in 165 chars, half an hour later. And they got 2 upvotes for it.